# Segmentation fault when read char* using sockets

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault

So I'm writing an app client-server in C, client asks server for time and server responds with it. I am doing it using struct. I get segmentation fault when I try to read from server in client.c. 
I get segmentation fault at receiveTimeResponse and try to figure out why. I thought its because I didn't allocate memory for char* date, but I think I did.

Structures:

```
struct timeStructQuer{
    int header[4];
    int requestID;
};

struct timeStructResponse{
    int header[4];
    int requestID;
    int length;
    char* date;
};
```

server:

```
int main()
{
    //connection here 
    struct queryStruct myStruct;
    read(client_sockfd, &myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
    getCurrentTime(client_sockfd, myStruct);
}

void getCurrentTime(int client_sockfd, struct queryStruct str){
    int length;
    char* currentTime = malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);

    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
    length = sprintf (currentTime ,"%s", asctime (timeinfo));

    struct timeStructResponse response;
    response.date = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
    response.header[0] = 1;
    response.header[1] = 0;
    response.header[2] = 0;
    response.header[3] = 2;
    response.requestID = str.requestID;
    response.length = length;
    response.date = currentTime;

    write(client_sockfd, &response, sizeof(response));
}
```

Client:

```
int main()
{
    //connection here
    sendTimeQuery(sockfd);
    receiveTimeResponse(sockfd);

    exit(0);
}

void sendTimeQuery(int sockfd){

    struct queryStruct myStruct;

    int randomN = rand();
    myStruct.header[0] = 0;
    myStruct.header[1] = 0;
    myStruct.header[2] = 0;
    myStruct.header[3] = 2;
    myStruct.requestID = randomN;

    write(sockfd, &myStruct, sizeof(myStruct));
}

void receiveTimeResponse(int sockfd){       
    struct timeStructResponse response;
    response.date = malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
    printf("seg2");
    read(sockfd, &response, sizeof(response));
    printf("Current time: %s", response.date);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read(sockfd, &response, sizeof(response));` will overwrite previously alocated `response.data` pointer with invalid value. The problem is that you can not transfer pointers (actually you can but the pointer value will be invalid on the other side). You need to transfer data they point to. So write should look like this:

```
/* TODO check write results... */
write(client_sockfd, &response.header, sizeof(response.header));
write(client_sockfd, &response.requestID, sizeof(response.requestID));
write(client_sockfd, &response.length, sizeof(response.length));
write(client_sockfd, response.date, response.length);
```

and read like this:

```
/* TODO check read and malloc results, length, and date is properly null-terminated... */
read(sockfd, &response.header, sizeof(response.header));
read(sockfd, &response.requestID, sizeof(response.requestID));
read(sockfd, &response.length, sizeof(response.length));
response.date = (char *) malloc(response.length);
read(sockfd, response.date, response.length);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great.